# Can't select Properties when logging into Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

SQL Server/SSRS 2016 Developer, installed on my local laptop, Windows 10 Pro.

My login is an admin to SQL Server, I'm able to do everything.  For SSRS, when I try to connect to my web portal url I'm told "You are not allowed to view this folder.  Contact your administrator to obtain the necessary permissions."  Connecting to the web service url I get this message, "The permissions granted to user are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)".  When I connect to Reporting Services with my login in SSMS it connects but I'm not able to do anything - when I right-click on anything the Properties options are not available.

I have run IE as administrator and added the web portal url to trusted sites.  I've run SSMS as administrator and connected to Reporting Services, same problems.  I can run Reporting Services Configuration Manager as administrator and have no problems there.  It seems like somehow when I setup SSRS my account didn't get added to the list of administrators for Reporting Services.

I did select * from ReportServer.dbo.Users and see these three:

- Everyone
- NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
- BUILTIN\Administrators

I have tried Chrome, IE, Edge, all as regular user and administrator.

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: Is your login in the `BUILTIN\Administrators` group on your laptop?

Comment: No it isn't, which is probably the problem.  I'll ask my IT security people to add it.  Thanks!